How to make multiple sectioning of the same rank in the book?
I have to make two new macros which produce headings of similar style like \section and passing to the table of contents and to the page headers items of the same rank as \section does it. The features that distinguish them from \section are:

The word "Experiment" before the sectioning number - for the first macro. The words "Summary of the experiment" before the sectioning number - for the second macro.
Both macros have a common counter which is not reset throughout the whole book.

So I would like to get automatically all the parameters defining the \section and pass them to two new macros. How to do this in the Memoir class?
Draft of the code:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{70mm}{100mm}
\settrimmedsize{70mm}{100mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{50mm}{80mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{10mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{10mm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0mm}{0mm}
\checkandfixthelayout 


\begin{document}
\part{aaa}
\chapter{bbb}
\section{ccc}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{ddd}
\lipsum[1-1]
%\experiment[eee]
\lipsum[1-1]
%\shorten[fff]
\lipsum[1-1]
\chapter{ggg}
%\experiment[hhh]
\lipsum[1-1]
\part{iii}
\chapter{jjj}
%\shorten[kkk]
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{lll}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}


The heavy lifting is done by \@startsection.  Not shown but the last two arguments (#7 = short title (optional), #8=title) are passed on from \section to \@startsection.
\newcommand{\section}{%
  \sechook%
  \@startsection{section}{1}%  level 1
      {\secindent}%            heading indent
      {\beforesecskip}%        skip before the heading
      {\aftersecskip}%         skip after the heading
      {\normalfont\secheadstyle}} % font

